# Enabling mod_rewrite ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'd like to enable the mod_rewrite function on my webserver. Im using apache, according some sources on the internet the options should be in my httpd.conf file, but trust me I simply don't have that file. Can someone explain me how to enable mod-rewrite?

These are the files i've got: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httpd.conf` is the conf file on RHEL distro (Fedora, centos, oracle linux ...)

in your case you can update the `apache2.conf`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it.